# How do I remove an element from an array and insert into another position in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

For example suppose I have

```
$input = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

How would I remove element 5 and insert at position 2 leaving me with

0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7

Comment: I am very sure it is one of the things you don't want to do. Try to find another solution to whatever problem you have. Changing lists, especially inserting somewhere inside, can be quite expensive (very likely, though I'm not sure). Also most of the problems you want to solve this way, will go away if you just change your data structures in a way that search and sort functions can apply (in the DB if possible). Never manually reorder lists! Sometimes a genius coder might decide it really is the smartest solution. But that kind of person doesn't need to ask how to implement it, right? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$input = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
array_splice($input, 2, 0, array($input[5])); //Place the a new array in the 3rd place of array
unset($input[6]); //remove the fifth element
array_splice($input, 0, 0); //to update the indexes

echo "<pre>".print_r($input,1)."</pre>"; //to view the array
```

Method without the need to unset and rearrange the index

```
$input = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
array_splice($input, 2, 0, array_splice($input,5,1));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
)
```

Comment: Note that `unset`  doesn't update the array indexes!!!  It's safer to use `array_splice` there, too: `array_splice($input, 4, 1)`

Comment: And you'd better insert the actual value from the array, not something you made up, and just happens to work for your example.

Comment: @bart, your code omits 4. However I updated my answer to update the indexes also.

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
$moved = array_splice($input, 5, 1);
array_splice($input, 2, 0, $moved);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_splice();`  will do it for you http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-splice.php

EDIT :

```
array_splice(your_array,position_where_you_want_to_replace_your_number,1,replacement_number);
```

Never used it before, may I've made a mistake above, but it's a start, insn't it? :)

EDIT2 : above, you'll have to remove the second number which is still here with my function.

Comment: @Starx dit well like I wanted :p

Comment: umm... french seemed like a natural choice of language? D: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the function array_splice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

That will remove elements from an array and also insert.